# Swagger-ui oauth2login cors policy issue

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui

I have a spring boot application configured with security oauth2login.
When i try to test, via my browser, the redirection with google authentification thanks to oauth2login, with url : localhost:8080/user/test it's work fine. i am redirect to google authentification page.

But when i try the same endpoint on Swagger-ui i get : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
I am not redirect to google page.

How can i do to resolve my issue ?

Thanks